# How to use textview as a html page?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

So I have an Asynctask class with this codes and I just want to change the view of contents from text to html

```
    private class JSONP extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        content=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcontent);

    }


    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject tempjo = jp.getjsonfromurl(url);
        return tempjo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            news = result.getJSONArray(Tag_posts);

            for(int i = 0;i<news.length();i++){

                JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);

                String titles = c.getString(Tag_title);

                String contents = c.getString(Tag_content);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(Tag_title, titles);

                map.put(Tag_content, contents);

                newslist.add(map);

                ListAdapter list = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        newslist,
                        R.layout.listv,
                        new String[] {Tag_title,Tag_content},
                        new int[]{R.id.textView2, R.id.txtcontent});

                        mylist.setAdapter(list);

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i know the method must be something like

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(contents));
```

but i just don't know where to put this code? make another class or directly use it in my asynctask class

Comment: Where is your "html" variable? If you are talking about displaying the json, you can do it right after setting the adapter

Comment: its a String. I already got it with this code :    String contents = c.getString(Tag_content);

Comment: So just put your textview.setText() in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: As per my understanding textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html)); can not be done in list adapter. For this oyu have to make custom adapter and in getView method of custom adapter you can implement that